# remove / in .htaccess 301 Redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following command in my .htaccess `Redirect 301 /old-url https://www.website.com/new-page.php` , but in my url I'm redirected to `https://www.website.com/new-page/` How can I fix that without changing the entire structure of the website ?

Comment: There seems to be another rule that redirects any .php file to a url with the .php extension removed by a slash. I can't explain this happening otherwise. So just get rid of that additional rule.

Comment: Tried removing every other rules and still got the same problem

Comment: Finally found out how to solve that one :     `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`